# Google App Engine - ndb sorting by string? (Python)

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible to sort query results by StringProperty?

I have the following:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
     first_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
     last_name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
```

Now if I want to retrieve the stored entries from the database, I use this (it works):

```
user_query = User.query(ancestor=user_key(user_name))
```

But I want the result to be ordered by first_name, so I use this:

```
user_query = User.query(ancestor=user_key(user_name)).order(-User.first_name)
```

This DOES NOT work! I don't know what is wrong and it does not produce any errors, but no results show up anymore. All I get is an empty table :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an index for order to work.

Comment: Thank you! It's frustrating that there is no error thrown, order without an index just silently returns nothing...